# Cannot enable Health Records capabilities in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, healthkit

I'm setting up HealthKit as the [official manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/health_and_fitness_samples/accessing_health_records?language=objc) says to read user's Health records. I enabled it and passed all the three steps to make it work, but somehow the "Health Records" capability is disabled and I cannot check it. As the result, the app crashes saying it cannot authenticate a request to health records.

How can I enable it?

Xcode Version 10.0 beta 6 (10L232m) with iOS 12 SDK.

[image]

There is also an entitlement file:

[image]

Account settings:

[image]

My code:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(requestAccess:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  NSNull * null = [NSNull null];

  NSSet * recordTypes = [self recordTypes];

  HKHealthStore *store = [HKHealthStore new];
  [store requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil
                                readTypes:recordTypes
                               completion:^void (BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (success) {
      callback(@[null, @true]);
```

Crash report

```
Exception 'Authorization to read the following types is disallowed: HKClinicalTypeIdentifierMedicationRecord' was thrown while invoking requestAccess on target AppHealthRecords with params (
    259
)
callstack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010709429b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105777735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070940f5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   HealthKit                           0x0000000104dc7ec0 -[HKHealthStore _throwIfAuthorizationDisallowedForSharing:types:] + 540
    4   HealthKit                           0x0000000104dc6912 -[HKHealthStore _validateAuthorizationRequestWithShareTypes:readTypes:] + 224
    5   HealthKit                           0x0000000104dc6a82 -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:shouldPrompt:completion:] + 321
    6   HealthKit                           0x0000000104dc680f -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:] + 77
    7   app                                 0x0000000104574c43 -[AppHealthRecords requestAccess:] + 307
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010709b11c __invoking___ + 140
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070985b5 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 325
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107098a06 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    11  app                                 0x000000010461ec6a -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2810
    12  app                                 0x00000001046d5dd6 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 790
    13  app                                 0x00000001046d58ef _ZZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEiENK3$_0clEv + 127
    14  app                                 0x00000001046d5869 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 25
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001099c251d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001099c3587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001099ca058 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 720
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001099cab9b _dispatch_lane_invoke + 401
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001099d39c6 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 645
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000109d48fd2 _pthread_wqthread + 980
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000109d48be9 start_wqthread + 13
)
```

Comment: HKClinicalTypeIdentifierMedicationRecord is not legal record type. The only allowable types are subclasses of HKObjectType; HKCharacteristicType, HKQuantityType, HKCategoryType, HKWorkoutType, and HKCorrelationType)

Comment: @IvanGrishaev did you solve the problem ? I have same issue and there is still no solution for this as far I searched

Comment: @ACAkgul I managed to do that somehow but cannot remember now...

Comment: @IvanGrishaev I found the solution and will write as an answer below

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `Health Records` key to your entitlements file.

And make sure to add an entry for the `NSHealthClinicalHealthRecordsShareUsageDescription` key in `Info.plist`

Entitlements screenshot:
[image: Entitlements screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your project with a developer account to be able to switch on Health Records